# Amazon S3 specific folder for authenticated user through Cognito, return 403 for listObjects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create create a specific user folder in `s3`. All users authenticated through `Cognito`( Google provider ).
I have such policies for Cognito Role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fake-youtube-videos"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${accounts.google.com:sub}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fake-youtube-videos/${accounts.google.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And a bucket policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fake-youtube-videos",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "${accounts.google.com:sub}/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fake-youtube-videos/${accounts.google.com:sub}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I'm authentificate from frontend

```js
var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
AWS.config.apiVersions = '2012-10-17'
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:c1f4182d-4598-4c83-80ff-896b6bff632f',
    Logins: {
          'accounts.google.com': id_token
      }
});



var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'fake-youtube-videos'}, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
  console.log('The error', err);
})
```

Also [image: Disabled policies] eveyrthing is disable
I got 403 for a list of objects `Access denied`. I'm stuck. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It might be the value of `${accounts.google.com:sub}` that is causing problems. If you temporary modify the bucket policy by removing the condition and the path, does it work?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeap, it works. I removed `${accounts.google.com:sub}` from all policies. But, right now, the user starts to get a list of all objects, which located in a  `fake-youtube-videos` bucket. But my goal is to show only a list of objects under a specific folder, in this case, based on google id.

Comment: Great! So now we know that the issue is that particular value. If you put them back, try to figure out what value it is, then make sure the API calls use those values. For example, when listing the bucket, make sure that the Prefix is set correctly.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried to add  to bucket policy
```json
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${accounts.google.com:sub}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
```
and from javascript calling
 
```javascript
s3.listObjects({
              Bucket: 'fake-youtube-videos', 
              Prefix: AWS.config.credentials.identityId
            }, function (err, url) {
              console.log('The URL is', url);
              console.log('The error', err);
            })
```

Comment: Also 
```
s3.listObjects({
              Bucket: 'fake-youtube-shootsta-videos', 
              Prefix: '${ProfileId}'
            }, function (err, url) {
              console.log('The URL is', url);
              console.log('The error', err);
            })
``` where `ProfileId` i took from a google, which is equal sub. 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

Comment: It started work. Need time to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stuck with the same problem:

`var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId` 
is not the same as `accounts.google.com:sub`

As https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo `sub` is unique user id.

you should use

```js
var sub = profile.getId() //Which you can get from a google
s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'fake-youtube-videos', Prefix: sub}, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
  console.log('The error', err);
})
```

In a question, I made a mistake, I tried to get a list of objects on a root of a bucket, but when you are trying to make with a specific Prefix, you will get a list. 
@JohnRotenstein thanks for a pointing me out

Comment: Are you sure it is `Key`? It should probably be `Prefix`.